# PrimeNG datatable issue with resizable columns

Tags: angular, primeng

I've a strange issue with a PrimeNG p-datatable.
I setted resizableColumns and it works, but when I resize a column all text in table is selected, as you can see in following image.
This is my code:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="list" scrollable="true" [rows]="10" [style]="{'background-color':'#cecece'}" 
                        [paginator]="true" paginatorPosition="top" [pageLinks]="3" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20]"
                        resizableColumns="true" columnResizeMode="expand">
...
```

[image]
Is it a component bug? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide working code/plunkr that can reproduce the issue. The demos on Primeng website do not have such bug.

Comment: I tried with a page containing just a table and the error persist. I think it can be related to something in my app. I solved with a css rule which disable the text selection.

Comment: You should try this code use class to set min-max width .[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51075942/how-set-primeng-data-table-columns-auto-fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51075942/how-set-primeng-data-table-columns-auto-fit)